# How to display nth divs within a certain div using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple divs on a page and in a certain div there are more child divs that get floated to go across the page. I want to be able to use javascript to see the width of the window and then divide my set width of the divs to work out how many to display.

I have found the 2 pieces of code. One that measures window width and the other to slice the divs and hide the rest.

```
$('div').slice(4).hide();



var width = $(window).width();
$(window).resize(function(){
   if($(this).width() != width){
      width = $(this).width();
       console.log(width);
       alert(width);
   }
});
```

My Problem is how to select only the divs within my speciedfied div. I have tried this but it hasn't worked. Don't even know if i'm goin in the right direction

```
$("#mainContent2").append(('div').slice(4).hide());
```

Is javascrpt the right way to go about this or would css be able to do what I'm after?

Many Thanks

EDIT: HTML

```
<div id='mainContent>
<p></p>
<div>
<div id='mainContent2'>
<div><img></img><p></p></div>
<div><img></img><p></p></div>
<div><img></img><p></p></div>
<div><img></img><p></p></div>
<div><img></img><p></p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: $(#mainconetent2). should be $('#mainconetent2'), note the -> ' also the miss-spelled maincontent might be it.

Comment: @Alex Was just a typing error here. No mistakes the project. Just double checked.

Comment: CSS would be the better option. And please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: @popnoodles could css change how many div were displayed when the browser was resized without reloading the page?

Comment: google css media queries

Comment: @popnoodles css media queries look very interesting but the javascrpit answer works for me right now, and it's what I need now. I Will definitly keep this in mind for our mobile site such. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have got the number of div to show in particular div then you can use this code.

```
 $(#mainconetent2 > div).slice(4).hide());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I correctly understood your problem, but JQuery offers the [child-selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) for selecting children of a specific element. Then you have access to its parameters and can set whatever you want.